# Sprite vibrates. What is wrong?

Tags: c#, xna

My enemy sprite vibrates all the time after it has reached the variable endposition. What is wrong? Why is it vibrating?
In addition, the variable next_position is never true. But why? I want that the enemy sprite moves to a new random endposition after it reached the current endposition.

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Texture2D enemy;
    Vector2 position, endposition;
    bool next_position = false;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1280;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 720;
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {          
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {         
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        enemy = Content.Load<Texture2D>("zombie");
        Random randomstart = new Random();
        position = new Vector2(randomstart.Next(100, 200), randomstart.Next(100, 200));
        endposition = new Vector2(randomstart.Next(100, 600), randomstart.Next(100, 400));
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        float delta = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;         
        Random random = new Random();
        position.X += 5 * delta;
        position.Y += 3 * delta;

        if (next_position == true)
        {
          endposition = new Vector2(random.Next(100, 600), random.Next(100, 400));
          next_position = false;
        }

        if (Vector2.Dot(endposition - position, endposition - position) > 0 || Vector2.Dot(endposition - position, endposition - position) < 0) 
        {
          Vector2 enemyDirection = Vector2.Normalize(endposition - position) * 100f;
          position += enemyDirection * delta;
        }
        else
        {
            next_position = true;
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(enemy, position, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try converting any non-integral values in your position to integral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am slightly confused by what the line

```
if (Vector2.Dot(endposition - position, endposition - position) > 0 || Vector2.Dot(endposition - position, endposition - position) < 0)
```

is supposed to do exactly.
From the rest of the code what you are trying to achieve with it, is checking whether the sprite's position is the enemy's position.
What the line actually does is calculating dot products of vectors in opposite directions, which will never be zero, unless the vectors are zero. So in theory this might actually work, but only if the position equals the enemy's position precisely.

However, you are moving the sprite a fixed distance per unit of time, and so it actually does not reach the enemy but overshoots it. Finding itself then on the other side it moves back, where it came from, and overshoots it again. This continues and results in the vibration you describe.

Now, the way the behaviour you want to implement is usually done is calculating the distance between the two objects(sprite and enemy), using Pythagoras' theorem, and then accepting the arrival of the object when the distance is either below a certain threshold(easy but prone to error), or shorter than the distance the object could travel this particular update(in your case, since you move by a normalized vector times `100f * delta`, this distance is equal to `100f * delta`).

I hope my explanation is helpful.
Of course, feel free to ask for clarifications.

**Edit(response to comment):**

The `limit` vector you are creating is relatively meaningless, as it is just the position offset by `max_distance` in both x and y direction. There is no need for anything like that.
However, the other `if()` includes pretty much the code you want, check this out:

```
// first you calculate the distance we can move this update
float max_distance = 100f * delta;

// now, we compare the actual distance to the end position to that maximum
// if the actual distance is larger, then we are not there yet
// otherwise, (if the actual distance is smaller) we will overshoot the target,
// thus we are in fact there! (=close enough to continue)
// (note: we compare the distances squared to avoid a square root,
//  which makes this check much faster, which is good practice,
//  in case we ever scale this up to more objects)
if ((position - endposition).LengthSquared() > max_distance * max_distance)
{
    /* we are not yet there, continue moving! */
}
else
{
    /* we are there! */
}
```

It really is this simple and no other check is needed. Let me know if this works out for you!

Comment: I understood the problem, but I still have difficulties to fix it. My changes don't work: float max_distance = 100f * delta;
            Vector2 limit = new Vector2(position.X + max_distance, position.Y + max_distance);
            if ((position - endposition).LengthSquared() > 25)
            {
                if ((position.X < limit.X)  && (position.Y < limit.Y))
                {
                  Vector2 enemyDirection = Vector2.Normalize(endposition - position) * 100f;
                  position += enemyDirection * delta;
                }
            }
            else ...

Comment: @Andy Edited my post with a bit of hopefully helpful code. Your code already has pretty much all you need, just a bit too much actually. Let me know how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

It’s better now, but not perfect. The enemy sprite doesn’t vibrate anymore, but it always moves some pixels down right if it has reached the end position. Why does it always move some pixels down right?
The rest works fine.

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Texture2D enemy;
    Vector2 position, endposition;
    bool next_position = false;
    int count_nextposition;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1280;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 720;
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        enemy = Content.Load<Texture2D>("zombie");
        Random randomstart = new Random();
        position = new Vector2(randomstart.Next(100, 200), randomstart.Next(100, 200));
        endposition = new Vector2(randomstart.Next(100, 600), randomstart.Next(100, 400));
        count_nextposition = randomstart.Next(90, 121);
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        float delta = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        count_nextposition -= 1;
        Random random = new Random();
        position.X += 5 * delta;
        position.Y += 3 * delta;

        if (count_nextposition <= 0)
        {
        if (next_position == true)
        {
            endposition = new Vector2(random.Next(100, 600), random.Next(100, 400));
            next_position = false;
        }
        float max_distance = 100f * delta;
        if ((position - endposition).LengthSquared() > max_distance * max_distance)
        {
           Vector2 enemyDirection = Vector2.Normalize(endposition - position) * 100f;
           position += enemyDirection * delta;
        }
        else
        {

            next_position = true;
            count_nextposition = random.Next(90, 121);
        }
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(enemy, position, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be the lines `position.X += 5 * delta; position.Y += 3 * delta;`? This would move the position a bit to the bottom right each update, regardless of what else is going on. So, unless these lines serve some other purpose, what happens when you remove them?